# List of parameters sent by Paypal in a after payment as a webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, payment-gateway

In a tutorial of how to integrate paypal payment, there's this code:

```
  def webhook
    st = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
      @registration = Registration.find(params[:invoice])
      @registration.update_attributes(notification_params: params, status: status,
                                      transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now)
    end
  end
```

My question: **Where is the documentation for the list of all the parameters sent back from paypal to my webapplication as a webhook?**

I'm trying to find the documentation, but there's no "txn_id", "status" in the current documentation for webhooks https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/

Comment: can you have `webhook` just print the `params` hash to a log file, i.e. `Rails.logger.info(params.inspect)`.

Comment: or just put a binding.pry and see the params